# Unable to use Com4j to work with QC object model

Tags: java, exception, com4j

Situation: I got successful in connecting to my QC with com4j and java

java code:

```js
ITDConnection itdc= ClassFactory.createTDConnection();
System.out.println(itdc.connected());
itdc.initConnectionEx(url);
System.out.println(itdc.connected());
itdc.connectProjectEx(domainName, projectName, userName, password);

// project name
System.out.println(itdc.projectName());
```

But i can't do any cast from object

```
ITestFactory itf=(ITestFactory) itdc.testFactory();
```

this fail with 
Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy11` cannot be cast to `test.ota.ITestFactory`

Please help

Answer (score 4):

You can't cast COM objects directly. Use the object's queryInterface method instead:

```
TargetType castObject = myObject.queryInterface(TargetType.class);
```

See `Casting and QueryInterface` in
http://com4j.java.net/runtime-semantics.html